# Change color of Textview in Listview

Tags: android, listview, colors, textview, baseadapter

I'm very new to Android and I wanna change the textcolor of a TextView in a Listview. When trying this, the color won't change. Who can help me with this (simple?) problem?

I use the following code in my "BaseAdapter" to control the ListView:

```
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    if (view == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cijfer_listitem, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mCijferTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cijferTxt);
        holder.mVakTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vakTxt);
        holder.mVakUitgebreidTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vakUitgebreidTxt);
        holder.mIdTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idTxt);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    Cijfer cijfer = mCijfers.get(i);

    holder.mCijferTxt.setText(cijfer.getCijfer());
    holder.mVakTxt.setText(cijfer.getCursus());
    holder.mVakUitgebreidTxt.setText(cijfer.getCursusUitgebreid());
    holder.mIdTxt.setText("" + cijfer.getCijferID());

    if (cijfer.isDef() == true ){

        holder.mCijferTxt.setTextColor(R.color.colorTxtDef);
    }
    else{
        holder.mCijferTxt.setTextColor((R.color.colorTxtConcept));
    }

    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView mCijferTxt;
    public TextView mVakTxt;
    public TextView mVakUitgebreidTxt;
    public TextView mIdTxt;
}
```

I wanna change the color of the TextView "cijferTxt".

Hope this is enough info for you to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the text color to a color resource ID (which is just an ID pointing to a color). You need to extract the color from this color resource ID.
Example:

```
int color = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTxtDef);
holder.mCijferTxt.setTextColor(color);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 holder.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTxtDef));
```